# Zip/unzip my directory on windows 7 cmd

Tags: windows, command-line, compression

I want to zip a directory containing many types of files and many sub-directories in it. I tried:

```
compact /c file
```

But I did not see anything. Next I found about zip/unzip command and tried:

```
zip file.zip file
```

It worked. But, there were sub-directories which have contents (in the input folder before zipping it) and now, in the zipped file, in that sub-directory, there is no content. It means during compression it did not store the contents of sub-directory.
What DOS command (only) can get me out of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `-r` option like so:

```
zip -r foo.zip foo
```

This will tell zip to recurse down the directory `foo`.

Comment: @stefan-palleta: for unzipping it... do i just write unzip ?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use PowerShell v5.0+.

To zip:

```
Compress-Archive -LiteralPath 'C:\mypath\testfile.txt' -DestinationPath "C:\mypath\Test.zip"
```

To unzip:

```
Expand-Archive -LiteralPath "C:\mypath\Test.Zip" -DestinationPath "C:\mypath" -Force
```

Sources:

- [Compress-Archive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/compress-archive?view=powershell-6)
- [Expand-Archive](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-6)

Special thanks to @Ramhound